# Why isn't wearing two belts a problem with protecting clothing?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, mishnah-berurah

As per Shulchan Aruch [OC 301:13](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1509), one is not allowed to wear/carry a garment whose sole purpose is to protect other clothing that he is wearing ("אצולי טינוף"), though if those also protect the wearer then it's allowed.

Ramma ([301:36](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50327&st=&pgnum=402)) writes that one shouldn't wear two belts, one on top of the other, because if one only needs a single belt, the other belt is a "משאוי," a burden, and cannot be worn on Shabbos.

Mishna Berura writes ([301:134](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50327&st=&pgnum=402)) that women who wear a belt over a too-long robe, and then hike up the belt and put on another belt so as to prevent the robe from dragging on the ground does not constitute a problem of two belts even according to those opinions who generally forbid two belts, because both belts have a purpose: one to hold the robe closed, and the other to prevent the robe from getting dirty, and therefore neither belt is a משאוי.

> כתבו האחרונים דמה שנוהגות קצת נשים לחגור בחגורה, ועוד חוגרים בחגורה על
>   הבגד הרחב מלמטה, ועל ידי כך הבגד הגבה בגד הרחב מן הארץ, **ועושין כן
>   שלא יתלכלך הבגד בעת שיש טיט ורפש, גם כן שרי, כיון שצרך הוא לכך**

**Why isn't the belt that holds the robe up, preventing the robe from getting dirty, forbidden as "אצולי טינוף" like the items listed in SA 301:13?**

Comment: Because nobody drags their hems in the mud; it's the way to get dressed when outside? (As in _I'm getting dressed for the muddy sidewalk_, not _I need to protect my skirt from the mud_.) Just guessing.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Perhaps...but then why isn't the כיס that the זב wears *the way a person gets dressed when he's a זב*? (see סעיף יג)

Comment: Because he's not getting dressed with the כיס. He's fine dressed w/o it. He wears it only to protect his clothes and only wears it when he drips. (So the meforshim explain, I'm pretty sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SA OC 301:14](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1510):

> דבר שהוא דרך מלבוש אפילו אם אינו לובשו אלא משום שצולי טינוף מותר לצאת
>   בו בשבת
>
> A thing that is worn in the normal manner of wearing, even if it's
>   only worn to protect clothing from getting dirty, is allowed to be
>   worn outside on Shabbos

(*translation mine*)